# R: counting instances of 1st consecutive conditional run from the last week

Tags: r

I have a data set that looks like the following (except has 100's of counties and 35 weeks per county):

```
week   county  tot_pct
1      1       2
2      1       3.5
3      1       4
4      1       NA
5      1       NA
6      1       8
7      1       9
8      1       9.3
9      1       NA
10     1       NA
1      2       NA
2      2       4
3      2       9
4      2       NA
5      2       NA
6      2       9.3
7      2       10
8      2       11
9      2       13
10     2       14.5
1      3       2
2      3       7
3      3       8.2
4      3       9
5      3       10
6      3       11.2
7      3       NA
8      3       NA
9      3       NA
10     3       NA
```

I need to calculate the number of total terminal weeks of tot_pct data points missing. Or in other words a count of a consecutive run starting from week 10, going backwards, where tot_pct==NA. The NA tot_pct run must include week 10, otherwise it is not considered "terminal".

The result of the given example should result in the following:

```
county term_miss_weeks
1      2
2      0
3      4
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

I have looked into rleid and have tried to create something that would achieve the result I'm looking for, but I can't quite get it right.

Here's the code I've tried:

```
df[is.na(tot_pct) & is.na(lag(tot_pct, 1)), run:=rleid(tot_pct), by=c("county")]
```

This creates a 1 in the "run" column that I've created. How could I change this to only limit to the first consecutive run going backwards from week 10 and create a counter instead of a column that just holds a 1 when the condition of `is.na(tot_pct) & is.na(lag(tot_pct, 1)` is met?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution, but you could use the custom function in `data.table` also

### Data

```
df <- structure(list(week = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), county = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), tot_pct = c(2, 3.5, 4, NA, NA, 8, 
9, 9.3, NA, NA, NA, 4, 9, NA, NA, 9.3, 10, 11, 13, 14.5, 2, 7, 
8.2, 9, 10, 11.2, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-30L))
```

### Function to check consecutive NA's

```
check_consecutive_NA  <- function(x) {
  
  n <- length(x)
  
  i <- 0
  
  out <- 0
  
  while(is.na(x[n+i])){
  
    out <- out + 1  
    
    i <- i-1
  }
    
  return(out)
}
```

### Libraries

```
library(dplyr)
```

### Code

```
df %>% 
  group_by(county) %>% 
  summarise(term_miss_weeks = check_consecutive_NA(tot_pct))
```

### Output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  county term_miss_weeks
   <int>           <dbl>
1      1               2
2      2               0
3      3               4
```

Answer (score 0):

Drop all the data after week 10 and for each `county`, if the 10th week is `NA` count consecutive occurrence of it or else return 0.

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

df %>%
  arrange(county, week) %>%
  group_by(county) %>%
  filter(week <= 10) %>%
  group_by(county) %>%
  summarise(term_miss_weeks = if(is.na(last(tot_pct))) 
                                sum(rleid(rev(tot_pct)) == 1) else 0)

#  county term_miss_weeks
#   <int>           <dbl>
#1      1               2
#2      2               0
#3      3               4
```